# How to modify scope of imported library using CMake

Tags: cmake

CMake question,

Imported library has scope in the directory in which it is created and below.

If I want to use this library in parent scope, what should I do?

for example,

top CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(sub)
add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp imported_lib)
```

sub CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(imported_lib STATIC IMPORTED)
```

Thanks for your helping~~

Answer (score 2):

Unlike classic libraries, imported libraries are scoped to the directory.
This can be changed using the `GLOBAL` options.

Here is an [extract from the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries):

> The target name has scope in the directory in which it is created and below, but the GLOBAL option extends visibility.

Example:

```
add_library(imported_lib STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
```

As far as I can tell, this option has always been available.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything, CMake will resolve this dependency automatically. See the documentation for [add_subdirectory](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_subdirectory):

> If a target built by the parent project depends on a target in the subdirectory, the dependee target will be included in the parent project build system to satisfy the dependency.

This is in contrast to the set() and list() commands, which require passing an explicit PARENT_SCOPE parameter.

Comment: This library is used by many targets. I hope I don't need to modify the subdirectory everytime I add a new target.

Comment: In that case you might need to write a find script. See the documentation for find_package for details.